# DNS Client Event Warnings on a Rigid Schedule

Tags: windows-7, router, dns

For several months, DNS Client Event warnings have been occurring on a very regular schedule - every 75 minutes.  Occasionally an additional "off schedule" DNS warning will occur.  Also occasionally the entries will discontinue for a few hours or even a day or two, but they always resume and continue for a week or more.

For exactly 10 minutes following the posting of any scheduled warning, no new internet connection can be made.  If the browser (IE 11) is launched, the rotating arrow and "Waiting for ..." appears and will continue for the entire 10-minute period, after which the home page will appear.  If I issue a ping command for any URL during such a period, there is no complaint, absolutely no response of any kind.

I am running under Win 7 Pro on a Dell T1700 with a Cisco DPC3825 residential gateway.  The following is a portion of the event log.  The URLs shown are the URLs which appear in the warning entries:

Parentheses surround log entries which are "extra", not members of the
75-minute pattern. Asterisks mark entries which are NOT DNS Client
Events - all other entries are DNS events.

I removed power from the Cisco gateway at about 08:47, causing the
e1dexpress warnings (*). The purpose was to see if this permanently
altered the DNS event times, which would suggest that the problem
might be in the gateway itself. Note, however, that the temporary
gateway power-off did not alter the 75-minute cycle.

```
09/06  
    06:48:16 PM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  
    08:03:16 PM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  
   (08:46:56 PM  *network link is disconnected [gateway powered off])  
   (08:48:06 PM  *[repeated])  
   (08:48:19 PM  *[repeated])  
   (08:48:40 PM  dns.msftncsi.com)  
   (08:48:54 PM  dns.msftncsi.com)  
   (08:49:27 PM  www.cnn.com)  
    09:19:39 PM  updatekeepalive.mcafee.com  
    10:33:16 PM  settings-win.data.microsoft.com  
    11:48:16 PM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  
   (11:50:42 PM  ws12.gti.mcafee.com)  

09/07  
    01:03:16 AM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  
    02:14:46 AM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  [not sure whichis "extra"]  
    02:20:59 AM  vortex-win.data.microsoft.com [not sure which is "extra"]  
    03:33:16 AM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  
    04:48:18 AM  vortex-win.data.microsoft.com  
   (04:50:45 AM  www.microsoft.com)  
    05:58:56 AM  ?tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org [not sure]  
    07:10:45 AM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  [time has shifted -8 minutes]  
    08:33:16 AM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org  [time exactly back on track]  
    09:48:16 AM  vortex-win.data.microsoft.com  
   (09:50:46 AM  crl.microsoft.com)  
    11:02:23 AM  tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org
```

---

Also, here is the result of ipconfig:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : f**************************1  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B**********************************1}:  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: The URLs shown in the partial log are the URLs shown in the warning entries.

Comment: Have you tried configuring your gateway to use different DNS servers?  Can you configure your Windows computer to bypass the gateway for DNS and experience any improvement (e.g. try `8.8.8.8` which are Google's DNS servers)